# For Loop Half Pyramid Vertical - Java

Tags: java, for-loop

[image]

how to this?

This is my Code

```
import java.util.*;
class ForLoopPyramids {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);

        int a;
        System.out.println("The Input is: ");
        a=x.nextInt();
        int c;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
                if (j <= i) {
                    c = a+j;
                    System.out.print("  "+i);
                } else {
                    System.out.print("   ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

But this is my output

```
The Input is: 
5
  0            
  1  1         
  2  2  2      
  3  3  3  3   
  4  4  4  4  4
```

But i want my output to be

```
  5  5  5  5  5              
  4  4  4  4         
  3  3  3      
  2  2   
  1
```

Comment: you are not far, keep trying

Comment: @njzk2 is right. And since it is some hours more, this homework question deserves an additional hint: experiment specifically with the setup of the for loops; start value, end value, counting direction etc. You might also spend the effort for typing in the assignment, instead of posting a photo. That might have saved you some downvotes. Take the [tour] please, to learn about asking good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach, start with `i` at `a` and loop down to `0`, also your inner loop only needs to be from `0` to `i` and you might use formatted io. Something like,

```
for (int i = a; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.printf("% 2d", i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Which outputs (with `a` of `5`) as requested

```
 5 5 5 5 5
 4 4 4 4
 3 3 3
 2 2
 1
```

**Alternatively**, using Java 8+, and `IntStream`(s) it *might* be implemented like

```
IntStream.range(0, a).mapToObj(i -> {
    return IntStream.range(0, a - i).mapToObj(j -> {
        return new StringBuilder(" ").append(a - i);
    }).collect(Collectors.joining());
}).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Wow it really works thankss man ^^ but may i ask what is the meaning of % 2d and the printf because when i don't put "f" on print it doest work but when i do it works ... what is that?

Comment: This line, `System.out.printf("% 2d", i);` produces the same output as the following line, `System.out.print(" " + i);`

Comment: Reading manuals doesn't kill: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html